# .dtsconfig File Location

Tags: package, scheduled-tasks, config, ssis

I'm trying to replace a scheduled job which runs a .dtsx file with the same .dtsx file, modified.

I want to use the same .dtsxonfig file as the old package, but I don't know where it is located. How can I find the location of the config file? How can I ensure the new package will reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current sql agent job provides an explicit path for the configuration, the job step will list that (grab the details from the Command Line tab).

Otherwise, look inside the package. SSIS, Package Configurations... and look for a Configuration Type of `XML configuration file`

### Update

In your control flow, right click on the background and in the context sensitive menu, select `Package Configurations...` If they have turned on configurations, I would expect the "Enable package configurations" check box to be checked and the section below that to not be greyed out.

With XML configuration, you get two options with it. The first (Sample) is what is referred to as direct configuration. You can see the Configuration String specifies a specific location on disk that the package will examine when the package runs. The second (XmlEnv) option demonstrates indirect configuration. This works by using an environment variable, SSIS_CONFIG in my example, to determine the location of the .dtsConfig file

[image]

If you don't see anything listed in the Package Configurations section, then you can assume they are applying configuration at run-time. There are a few different ways of accomplishing this so I would ask your DBA to provide the details of the particular Agent's Integration Services job step.

Comment: I don't have the proper rights to view the SQL agent jobs. And I'm not seeing package configurations anywhere. Sorry for being a n00b, but can you clarify?

Comment: No worries about n00bosity, we all start somewhere. Updated my answer with how to find the configurations